# Why does KeyValueGroupedDataset's flatMapGroups give incorrect result when running locally?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

KeyValueGroupedDataset's flatMapGroups seems to give an incorrect result when running locally. It gives the correct result when running the same query in a Databricks notebook. Is there any misconfiguration with my local Spark setup that could cause this? Is this a bug in Spark?

Here is a minimal reproduction case:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object FlatMapGroupsBug {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("Bug reproduction")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    Seq(1, 2).toDS
      .groupByKey(x => x)
      .flatMapGroups((_, _) => Seq(1, 2, 3))
      .show
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Here is the result when running locally in IntelliJ or with `sbt`:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    3|
|    3|
|    3|
|    3|
|    3|
|    3|
+-----+
```

Running the same query in a Databricks notebook gives the expected result:

[image: Correct execution on Databricks]

Comment: How are you running locally? Are you sure you're running the code you think you are?

Comment: Running via sbt with `sbt "runMain FlatMapGroupsBug"` and in IntelliJ through the Scala plugin both give the same unexpected result. My build.sbt is minimal: https://pastebin.com/WMiHy8gx

Comment: Downgrading to Scala 2.12 fixes the issue..

Comment: I created an issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-47061

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem right now and I'm using this workaround:

```
ds.groupByKey(x => x.id)
  .mapGroups((key, iter) => {...})
  .flatMap(identity)
```